# How to I split date and time that are on the same column and store them in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, bufferedreader

I'm creating a data visualisation program using 'JFreeChart' and i'm having trouble reading data from a CSV file using BufferedReader. In the CSV file I have the date and time stored in the same column. I know that I have to use the " " function to separate them but I can't figure out how to go around doing so.

I have tried looking everywhere but I can't put my finger on it. I need to be pushed onto the right track.

```
//This is part of my Data Class

private int millis;
    private int stamp;
    private int light; 
    private double temp;
    private double vcc;
    private Time theTime;
    private Date theDate;


//This is part of another class

public class CSVreader {

    private List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    private String path;

    public List<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void readCSV() throws IOException{ 

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(path));

        String line = in.readLine();

        while(line != null) {

            Data d = new Data();

            String[] splits = line.split(",");

            int millis = Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
            int stamp = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
            int light = Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(splits[3]);
            double vcc = Double.parseDouble(splits[4]);

            d.setMillis(millis);
            d.setStamp(stamp);
            d.setLight(light);
            d.setTemp(temp);
            d.setVcc(vcc);

            dataList.add(d);

        }

        }

}
```

The end result should be that all the data will be on an arraylist and I can bring up those results and from the List I can create a graph using JFreeChart.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem in your code - which of your columns are you having troubles reading? It might help to share a sample line of your CSV file. Also, note that you are skipping `splits[2]` - is that on purpose?

Comment: Here is a sample line of the CSV;  
2000, 1273010255, 2010/5/4 21:57:35, 333, 78.32, 3.92

Comment: I'm having trouble reading the date/time which is, '2010/5/4 21:57:35'

Comment: `private Time theTime;` is this custom? @A.uddin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment split the 3 element in `splits` array by space `" "` delimiter

```
String dateTime[] = splits[2].split(" ");
String date = dateTime[0];
String time = dateTime[1];
```

But i can see datatype of `date` and `Time` are different

```
private Time theTime;
private Date theDate;
```

If `Date` is `java.util.Date` you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert string to `Date`

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/mm");
Date date = formatter.parse(testDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment to read '2010/5/4 21:57:35' date/time,
for easier way can use [Joda Time Library](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2010/5/4 21:57:35");
```

and then can get the date and time value from Datetime:

```
String time = dt.toString("HH:mm:ss");
String date = dt.toString("yyyy/M/d");
```

but I see that the datatype is not String, if you want to parse it into Date datatype can do like this :

```
Date date = dt.toDate();
```